# icons in full calender event

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, fullcalendar

I am working on full calendar in c#  MVC i want to show a icon on each events at the endof each event in calendar.i am using

```
eventRender: function(event, element, calEvent) {
                                element.find(".fc-event-title").after($("<span class=\<img src="~\Content\images\ui-bg_flat_15_cd0a0a_40x100.png\></span>"));
                            },
```

but it is not showing any icon ..what should be the syntax in the  eventrender

Comment: Your image source is incorrect. `~` is for use on server controls, not regular `img` tags. The code is incorrect anyway, both in the way you used quotes and that for the `span` class... you have an `img` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this (v2 of fullCalendar):

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    element.find(".fc-title").append('<img src="/path/to/image/image.png">'));
},
```

Comment: feel free to upvote and accept this answer if it worked for you.